# Where to find a video uploaded from Final Cut Pro X?

Tags: facebook

Where can I find a video that I uploaded to Facebook from Final Cut Pro X (v10.4)? I set the options from FCPX as visible only by me, and after it was uploaded I clicked the button "Visit" from the desktop notifications, but the video is not available anywhere on my Facebook profile page neither any of my Facebook pages.

Comment: Welcome. Have you tried uploading any videos from a different source? Can you find those? If yes, that it is probably wiser to seek for help from Final Cut.

Comment: @marikamitsos I added an answer explaining why sharing to Facebook from FC is no longer possible.

Comment: Great. Now -as you probably know- you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)  it as well.

Comment: @marikamitsos Done! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an update in Feb. 2019 where Apple said it wasn't possible to share directly to Facebook:

> Because of an update to the way Facebook handles sharing, it's no longer possible to share directly to Facebook from iMovie for macOS, Final Cut Pro X, or Compressor.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208977